# Altering WordPress Link Structure for Portfolio

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible / easy to change the permalink format for portfolios?

I want to have a page called projects, and each “portfolio’ item as a project.

[Site](http://tylerandassoc.com/)

So /projects

and each project is under that: /projects/example/

instead of /projects -> /portfolio/example/

Comment: hi @Leigh McKenzie did my answer helped you, if it did please mark it as answer. thanks

Comment: have you tried to change the slug of the `Project` page ?

Comment: Changed format of link

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but I think that the author of the theme that named this custom post type as 'portfolio' can alter it in the code of the theme,, . It can be hacky to change it on your own because you may break things..

You can try to ask the developers of the theme that you bought to help you with that, I belive it is this theme

http://centum.purethe.me/

right?

Hope they can help you with that, and if not, I'm afraid if you do not post some specific code than community can't help you much either,,,

hth, k

Answer (score 0):

You should check the files of the theme and look for the file where the portfolio posttype is added. You could add here the following code to rewrite the slug.

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'project',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
```

Most of the time the file where the posttypes are added are in the 'lib' folder or something like that.